# PHP remove characters after a specific string for a certain length

Tags: php, substr, strlen

I have a string that is:

```
<p><img src="../filemanager/image.png?1476187745382"/></p> some text ...
```

I would like to remove everything after a `.png` or `.jpg` when question mark occurs. The goal is to remove the timestamp added `?1476187745382` but not the `"/></p>` some text ...

Keeping in mind that the timestamp, will change and the what comes after the the image `>` will also be different.

I have looked at different solutions, but they all remove either the exact occurrence or everything after a certain character, which is not what I need to do.

This is what I have looked at:

1. [PHP remove characters after last occurrence of a character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10746695/php-remove-characters-after-last-occurrence-of-a-character-in-a-string)
2. [Remove portion of a string after a certain character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588666/remove-portion-of-a-string-after-a-certain-character)

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not always needed, but a regex will do it:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\?[\d]{13}/', '', $string);
```

If the timestamp is not always 13 digits then replace the `{13}` with just a `+`.

Comment: The character class is not needed.  If the "some text" contains a long set of consecutive integers, they'll be purged too.

Answer (score 0):

$path = "../filemanager/image.png?1476187745382";

$subpath = explode('?',$path)[0];